# Como tratar mensajes de error en django crispy forms

Tags: python, bootstrap, django, login, django-forms

Estoy utilizando el sistema de autenticación de django por defecto, y lo renderizo mediante crispy-forms.

Hasta ahí bien, el problema viene cuando quiero desplazar el mensaje de error que aparece por defecto en mi plantilla html.

**Intento moverlo desde arriba hasta abajo a la derecha:**

[image: Desplazamiento de caja de texto]

Realmente no se como tratar los mensajes de error sobre un formulario generico (en este caso AuthenticationForm) y la cosa se complica cuando estoy representando el formulario mediante un FormHelperLayout ( puesto que no encuentro la forma en la que se tratan estos mensajes de error en la documentacion)

Este es mi codigo por si sirve de ayuda: (Estoy utilizando Bootstrap 5)

**login.html**

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% crispy form %}  
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=None)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_id = "id-authenticationForm"
    self.helper.form_class = "form-signin"
    self.helper.form_method = "post"
    self.helper.form_action = "login"
    self.helper.layout = Layout(

        
            HTML("""{% load static %}<img class="mb-4" src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" >
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>"""),

            FloatingField("username", "password"),
            
            Div(
                Div(
                    Div("remember_me", css_class="checkbox mb-3"),css_class="col"),
                    Div(HTML("<p><a href='{% url 'password_reset' %}'>Lost password?</a></p>"),css_class="col"),
                css_class="row"
                ),

            Submit('submit', 'Sign in', css_class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary"),
            
            HTML("""<p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2022 all rights deserved</p>""")
            
            )
```